# Inserting polygon to mysql returns null

Tags: mysql, polygon

When I run

```
INSERT INTO zones (userId, typeId, name, coords, date) VALUES
(2, 3, "Name", PolygonFromText('POLYGON((41,395210 2,134008,41,385615 2,142463,41,393085 2,131133,41,385310 2,138665,41,395210 2,134008))'), now());
```

it returns NULL

I created a few polygons before with any problem. The difference is that coords have less digits than working ones.

Comment: looks like you're missing a few commas, for example: `385310 2`. Anyways, if we can't see the code of `PolygonFromText` it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of GeometryFromText? (I don't have experience, but that occurs about 10x as often in the MySQL documentation)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was that comas. Coords need to be like this:

```
41.395210 2.134008
```

Not like this:

```
41,395210 2,134008
```

I feel so stupid...